# Issue restoring a .tar file to a custom schema in pgadmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am having difficulties restoring a .tar file to a custom schema in pgadmin4...it restores fine when restored to the public schema but doesn't respond to the custom schema..

Comment: Give some more details about what you've tried and what happens

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL?